# Why is Moshe's election explained vs Avraham's where no reason is provided

Tags: moshe-rabbeinu, abraham, qualifications, backstory, introduction

Moshe is introduced to us with a dramatic story complete with three times that he took a brave stand in the face of injustice which presumably serve to explain to us why he was chosen to lead us as the most important requirement for a leader is loving justice with the bravery and courage to protect the oppressed.

On the other hand we are given absolutely no back story or reason for why Avraham was chosen to head up God's new nation which presumably should require more of an explanation so that it shouldn't look arbitrary vis a vis the other nations.

(The famous midrashim are presumably attempts to help explain this otherwise inexplicable election.)

Why the glaring difference?

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Netzach_Yisrael.11.14

Comment: God knew what Abraham was capable of doing before Abraham did anything to prove it.

Comment: Thank you guys. אילפא I am looking for something simpler and also don't understand why the general election itself doesn't need to be explained and Maurice I don't see why you can't say the same for Moshe

Comment: For Moshe it’s important to know where he came from because he used his Egyptian background to converse with pharaoh and whatnot

Comment: There's a sicha explaining that the Torah omits Avraham's background to emphasize the unique bond with Hashem created by mitzvos, לך לך being the first command to the first Jew.